# Difference between getExternalStorageDirectory and getExternalStoragePublicDirectory?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, permissions, storage

According to google one returns the primary shared/external storage directory and the other gets a top-level shared/external storage directory for placing files of a particular type. Can anyone explain in simple language and example?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I am going to assume that you have used a Windows computer sometime in your life.

`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`, if this were Windows, would return `C:\`.

`Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES)`, if this were Windows, would return some standard location on the `C:\` drive where the user would typically look to find saved movies.

Comment: Thank you for correct answer. i use linux, i have never seen window in my entire life not even bill gates.

Comment: @indian0girl: In that case, `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` would most closely map to `~` (user home), while `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES)` would map to `~/Movies`. That's not a great comparison, as `~` has different meaning in Linux, but it is the closest Linux desktop analogy that I can think of.