# Android: File written in external storage is not showing

Tags: java, android, filesystems

I'm trying to write a text file and save it in the android external storage, but file is not showing and I don't get any errors.

Here is my code:

```
String r;
String fname= "readme.txt";
r = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();

File myDir = new File(r);    
if (!myDir.exists()) {
    myDir.mkdirs();
}

File file = new File (myDir, fname);
if (file.exists ())
    file.delete (); 

try {
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
    Out.write(wfile)
    out.flush();
    out.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: change e.printStackTrace(); to Log.e("APP", "No Good!" +e); to see the error on LogCat... my guess is you did not grant the External_Storage_permission.

Comment: I think I have to try to read the file. And check the file and directory is existing or not. And I already grant the External_Storage_permission. But I don't no where is file saved. And also file is really saved or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something below. You can add validations to check whether file exists or not, as you please.

```
        File file =  new 
File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS), "readme.txt");
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        out.write(wfile);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(mContext, new String[] { file.toString() }, null,new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
            public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
                Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);
            }
       });
```

Just FYI, `Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS` may does not exists in older android versions. Then you may have to add a validation to check that and create a directory if not.

Comment: What is the difference between getExternelStroagePublicDirectory and getEnternelStroageDirectory and why you use MediaScannerConnection sacnFile?

Comment: Hope this can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44178065/difference-between-getexternalstoragedirectory-and-getexternalstoragepublicdirec